# Delphi TStringList efcreate error, file used by another process

Tags: delphi, tstringlist

Been searching everywhere but I can't seem to get this working. When i run this code I get a EFCreateError telling me that the file is used by another process. I'm kinda new to using TStringLists so I need your help! Thanks in advance!

This is where the error is generated: empFile.SaveToFile('Data\Emp\'+emp+'\'+emp+'.txt');

```
procedure TfmMain.btSaveRetClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    select, pos1, pos2, pos3, i: integer;
    fileBuffer, rentFile: TextFile;
    rCode, emp, buffer, retBuffer: string;
    empFile: TStringList;

begin
    if lbReturn.Items.Count <> 0 then 
    begin
        select:=Messagedlg('Retourner les items?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo],0);
        if select=mrYes then 
        begin
            empFile:=TStringList.Create;
            AssignFile(fileBuffer, 'Data\filebuffer.dat');
            AssignFile(rentFile, 'Data\rented.dat');
            lbReturn.Items.SaveToFile('Data\filebuffer.dat');
            Reset(fileBuffer);
            Reset(rentFile);

            repeat 
            begin
                ReadLn(fileBuffer, buffer);
                pos1:=AnsiPos('|', buffer);
                rCode:=AnsiLeftStr(buffer, pos1-2);
                repeat 
                begin
                    ReadLn(rentFile, retBuffer);
                    pos2:=AnsiPos(rCode, retBuffer);
                    if pos2<>0 then 
                    begin
                        pos3:=AnsiPos('|', retBuffer);
                        emp:=AnsiRightStr(retBuffer, (Length(retBuffer))-pos3-1);
                        empFile.LoadFromFile('Data\Emp\'+emp+'\'+emp+'.txt');
                        i:=empFile.IndexOf(buffer);
                        empFile.Delete(i);
                        empFile.SaveToFile('Data\Emp\'+emp+'\'+emp+'.txt');
                        empFile.Clear;
                    end;   
                end;
                until EOF(rentFile);
            end;
            until EOF(fileBuffer);
        empFile.Free;
        end;
    end 
    else 
    begin
        MessageDlg('Aucun item à enregistrer!', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Ok I found it! I just forgot to close a text file earlier in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EFCreateError is raised by an invalid file name, lack of access rights or lack of disk space: [info](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.EFCreateError)

Comment: yeah thatI know, whati'm trying to figure out is what's using this file.

Comment: You can use Process Explorer for that: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx
Ctrl+F shows a search dialog